# Qué hago si la notificación de JS se queda menos de un segundo y no me deja ni confirmar ni cancelar, sólo borra el registro

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

Ya intenté poner una condicional en el código de JS, después del `then`:

```js
.then((result) =>{
  if(result.value){
    window.location.href = "historial.php";
  }
```

Y si se eliminan los datos, pero me redirige inmediatamente sin haber podido presionar el botón de aceptar o cancelar.
Espero puedan ayudarme ya que es lo único que me falta para que mi página funcione correctamente.

Dejo el código que estoy usando en JS:

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {            
            $('.btn-danger').on('click', function() {
                swal({
                    title: '¿Estás seguro?',
                    text: "Esta acción no se puede deshacer",
                    icon: 'warning',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar',
                    cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar'
        
                }).then(function() {
                    window.location.href = "historial.php";
                });
            });                         
        
        });
```

Comment: hola, primero que nada te invito a que hagas el [tour], entonces el tiempo que dure la alerta no tiene nada que ver con php o phpmyadmin. saludos.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, inicialmente había puesto el código en PHP, para la conexión ala base de datos, pero lo ví innecesario y olvidé quitar las etiquetas, una disculpa.

Comment: No agregaré esto como respuesta, por que ahora mismo no puedo confirmarlo. Pero al momento realizar el click, estás enviando el formulario a pesar de que el javascript intente hacer algo. Agrega `event.preventDefault(); ` antes del Swal para evitar que esto suceda, si funciona, agregaré correctamente la respuesta.

Comment: Si deja que haga click en aceptar, pero ahora no borra los datos :(

Comment: Claro, por que ahora, no está enviando el formulario. Dejame explicarlo en una respuesta donde tendré mas espacio.

Answer (score 1):

Tu SWAL se cierra de manera automática dado que al hacer click en el botón del formulario, este se envía sin considerar lo que quiere hacer el ajax.

Para evitar esto, debemos agregar `event.preventDefault();` justo antes de la ejecución del Swal.

Pero ahora que hemos prevenido este comportamiento debemos reanudarlo, en el `then` agregaremos lo siguiente: `$(event.target).closest('form').submit();`

De todos modos, recomiendo realizar una confirmación con el resultado antes de realizar la redirección.

```
$(document).ready(function() {            
    $('.btn-danger').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        swal({
            title: '¿Estás seguro?',
            text: "Esta acción no se puede deshacer",
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar'
        }).then(function(result) {
            //Acá puedes agregar un if para manejar el resultado
            $(event.target).closest('form').submit();
        });
    });                         
});
```